# Expo XDE is stuck when opening one of my projects

Tags: react-native, expo

This has happened to me twice now when working on this project. I open the project using expo XDE and it just hangs there loading and never actually opening my project. The first time it happened I just created a new project and copied my code over. I don't want to keep doing that. I've seen posts where people talk about the wifi connection and mine is working just fine.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLs41.jpg

This second time around I tried running 'exp start' from the CLI when inside my project directory and I get this error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wF1Yi.jpg

I am able to open my other projects via the command line and with the expo XDE app.

Let me know if there is any other information I can provide!

Versions:

expo XDE: 2.24.4

npm ls react-native : react-native@0.55.4

npm ls expo : expo@28.0.0

npm -v : 6.1.0

node -v : v8.11.1

exp -V : 55.0.4

watchman version : 4.9.0

Comment: if it is stuck, there is probably something off with your code. however, with that being said, expo has been known to be a little buggy at times. Try uninstalling expo and re-installing it.

Comment: I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but that didn't seem to work. I just cloned my project from github. Seems to be my temporary fix